# get the task_id in celery

Tags: python, celery

How can I get the task id from the tasks.py in `celery`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from pig_engine.celery import app
import time

@app.task
def run(code):
    result = task_id /// How to get the task id
    return result
```

I know we can get the task id from 
run.delay().id , but how can get same id in tasks it self

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get task's info from [request](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#context) object

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def run(self,code):
    result = self.request.id #task id
    return result
```

Comment: I think you should pass `bind=True` to the decorator to be able to access `self`, it should be `@app.task(bind=True)`.